# Issues with audio file format in Node request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I am trying to work with the [Acast API](https://developers.acast.com/#27ae9e9c-463a-42c8-b7b6-e474c8420a47) to publish audio.

I am using the code from their documentation as follows, sending an audio file with Request:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://open.acast.com/rest/shows/5bcb76ef0d46b9226faefe92/episodes',
  'headers': {
    'x-api-key': 'secret'
  },
  formData: {
    'title': 'Episode Title',
    'subtitle': 'Episode Subtitle',
    'audio': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'),
      'options': {
        'filename': 'filename'
        'contentType': null
      }
    },
    'status': 'published'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

No matter what I do, the only response I get from the server is {"statusCode":400,"message":"audio file wrong format"}

The files I am sending are either mp3 or wav. I've tried both, with multiple different files, filling in the contentType and leaving it out. I'm at a dead end but I have a feeling it's just a lack of knowledge / missing something obvious on my part. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you always send `contentType : null`? Why not `contentType : 'audio/mpeg'` (for mp3) or `audio/wav` (for wav)?

Comment: No I tried null, audio/wav & audio/mpeg  - no effect! But as below, removing some of the data from the API call seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: there is also a limit `audio Required. Episode Audio File to upload. Should be 150Mb max`

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more playing, removing the extra details from the 'audio' formData seems to have solved the issue. I've edited from:

```js
'audio': {
  'value': fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'),
  'options': {
    'filename': 'filename'
    'contentType': null
  }
}
```

To:

```
'audio': fs.createReadStream('./audio/audioFile.mp3'),
```

This seems to have resolved it.